# Configure dev environment correctly to use memset_s function (C++)

Tags: c++, memset

I've to perform a call to the `memset_s` method but I've the error that is not defined.

I've declared **STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1** and set to 1 before including `string.h` file

```
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1
#include <string.h>
```

and I've defined the preprocessor variable **STDC_LIB_EXT1** so I can perform the call like this:

```
#ifdef __STDC_LIB_EXT1__
    memset_s(dest, sizeof(dest), 0, count);
#endif
```

This is recommended from the official page https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset to be guaranteed that the `memset_s` function is available. But even with these steps, I still get the error that memset_s is undefined.
So my question is, what's the next extra step I've to perform in order to use this function?

Some environment info:

- Windows SDK version: 10.0
- Platform toolset: v142
- C++ Language Standard: Default (ISO C++14 Standard)

Comment: `memset_s` is an __optional__ C11 function and it look like MSVC has not implemented it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/memset-wmemset?view=msvc-170

Comment: I guess your should include `cstring` not `string.h` if you want to use c++

Comment: The simplest answer for you is to implement `memset_s` all by yourself. Problem solved.

Comment: On Windows simply replace this call with [SecureZeroMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/aa366877(v=vs.85)) Win API macro designed exactly for secure memory clean.